# How do I control the snapping features in the Advanced Digitizing Panel in QGIS 3.0.3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, digitizing

I am using the QGIS (3.0.3) Advanced Digitizing Panel. I would like to control the spaping characteristics. The QGIS documentation states that by selecting the "gear" drop down icon...

> You can also control the snapping to features. The options are:
>
> • Do not snap to vertices or segments 
>   • Snap according to project configuration 
>   • Snap to all layers

However, when I select the "gear" the drop down menu does not contain these options. How do I control the snapping features in the Advanced Digitizing Panel in QGIS 3.0.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advanced snapping option are now in:

Project> Snapping Options>

Click on the magnet to turn on snapping

Drop down list next to the magnet choose "Advanced configuration".

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks for the concise and clear answer!